# Wald-test for single statistic in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a series of hazard-rates at two points (low and high point) in the curve with corresponding standard errors. I calculate the hazard-ratio by dividing the high point hazard-rate by the low point hazard-rate. This is the hratio column. Now in the next column I would like to show the probability (p-value) that the ratio is significantly different from 1 using the Wald-test.

I have tried doing this using the wald.test() from the aods3 package, but I keep getting an error messages. It seems that the code only allows for the comparison of two related regression models.

How would you go about doing this?

```r
> wald
     fit.low      se.low   fit.high     se.high    hratio
1 0.09387638 0.002597817 0.09530283 0.002800329 0.9850324
2 0.10941588 0.002870383 0.10831292 0.003061924 1.0101831
3 0.02549611 0.001054303 0.02857411 0.001368525 0.8922802
4 0.02818208 0.000917136 0.02871669 0.000936373 0.9813833
5 0.04857652 0.000554676 0.04897211 0.000568229 0.9919222
6 0.05121328 0.000565592 0.05142951 0.000554893 0.9957956
> library(aods3)
> wald$pv <- wald.test(b=wald$hratio)
Error in wald.test(b = wald$hratio) : 
  One of the arguments Terms or L must be used.
```

Answer (score 0):

define `L=NULL, Terms=NULL, Sigma = vcov(b)`

Comment: I get the same error msg : ```wald$pv <- wald.test(b=wald$hratio, L=NULL, Terms=NULL, Sigma = vcov(b))
Error in wald.test(b = wald$hratio, L = NULL, Terms = NULL, Sigma = vcov(b)) : 
  One of the arguments Terms or L must be used.```